# Symfony 3 security - Access_control doesn't work for one route

Tags: php, symfony, security, routes, roles

I'm currently working on a PDF generator, but I'm having a problem accessing the url.

Anyone should be able to download the PDF.
In my security.yml I currently have this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy: ~

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/gc/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I would like people to have access to the following url: `/admin/maintenance/pdf/{id}`

So I added the following line:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/gc/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin/maintenance/pdf/$, role: [ROLE_USER,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
```

But I'm still redirected to the login page when I'm not logged in.

I did several tests, and it is the following line that is problematic:

```
- {path: ^ /, role: ROLE_USER}
```

I guess I misconfigured my access to the url.

Someone can help me ?
Thank you

Comment: Move it up, so `^/admin/maintenance/pdf/$` is tested first

Comment: In fact it may worth to move it out of `admin` to the root: `^/maintenance/pdf/$` It seems it doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Items in ACL are processed sequently, so you need to put it before:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/gc/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/maintenance/pdf/$, role: [ROLE_USER,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Need to wait 1 minute haha :) I cant now ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Move up more specific rules, so that they are matched first.